# Circuit analysis Thevenin example in sinusoidal steady-state with dependent and independent ac sources

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductance, thevenin, homework

[image]

So I get really confused when I see a dependent source (and serial?) in thevenin-norton problems. Can you help me with these questions? 
(I think in the question of the figure b the value C is mistaken with R. It should be C instead of R=1 ohms)

Comment: Please try to go as far as you can, and show us as much as you understand about the problem. If you get stuck at a specific step we will try to help but we do not just hand out homework solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

a) I think Ix =0 so you just need apply KVL to find Vth.
Then you turn off V_k, connect at the terminal a I_s = 1A => Zth = V_AB*I_s
b)Open circuit at ZL then Apply KCL to find voltage across L and C that voltage is Vth
Then turn off I_s, open circuit at Zl => Zth= Z_L + Z_C
=> ZL = Zth*
=> Pmax = (|Vth|^2)/8ZL